# Form submit - HTML - domain name

Tags: html

Do I need to necessarily register my domain for setting it as a form action attribute. Cannot I directly use the IP address of a machine (hooked up to the internet) which is running a web server?

Basically I want to do something like `<form action ="<IP address>/process.php">`

Note: I cannot use relative addressing, since the form hosting page and the action page are in different machines.

Comment: You can obviously use IP address, just make sure the machines are accessible to each other over the network.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply use a relative address on your form like so...

```
<form actions="/confirm.php" method="post">
```

Although you should consider looking up wamp, where you can set up a domain on localhost in your windows host file and editing the apache config files.

Comment: That would not work for me. The form referral page is in a different machine from the action page.